# Working application stops working after Xcode crash

Tags: xcode, dylib

All,

I am developing an application in C++ which worked fine until couple of days ago I got Xcode crash.

After the crash, application was still successfully being built, but when running I am now getting an error that one my dylibs fails to load, because apparently the linker is trying to load it from /use/local/lib instead of from the Bundle.

Does anybody experienced something like this before? If yes - how do you fix it?

TIA!!